# Are the leaves of bean plants effective for controlling bed bugs?

Tags: natural-remedies, herbalism, entomology

From the National Geographic article [*Can We Fake Leaves That Stab Bed Bugs in the Feet?*](http://phenomena.nationalgeographic.com/2013/04/09/can-we-fake-leaves-that-stab-bed-bugs-in-the-feet/)

> But in the Balkan countries of southeastern Europe, there’s an old folk
>   remedy that might be the insects’ undoing.
>
> Before nightfall, people would scatter the leaves of **bean plants**
>   on the floor by their beds. In the morning, the leaves would be full
>   of immobilised bed bugs, which could then be taken outside and burned.

Its hot science news. But is it something I can try out for myself? Should I start sprouting beans and spreading the leaves around?

Does anybody have experience with this? Also what kind of beans/grams are ideal, since I live in India, [Asparagus beans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigna_unguiculata_subsp._sesquipedalis), [Green beans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_beans) and related species are the most common.

Comment: The same source explains "You could just scatter bean leaves, but these dry out fairly rapidly and they can only be applied to horizontal surfaces—they’d do nothing to trap bed bugs that are already living in a mattress."